# Having issues installing nodejs/npm

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I've completely uninstalled nodejs/npm both.

However they seem to be throwing same error consistently whilst installing.
I've also tried sudo-apt get update
sudo apt cache verify and apt cache search, when I search nodejs is not found or npm.

```
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

And when I do sudo apt-get intall nodejs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nodejs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nodejs' has no installation candidate
```

I've made sure nodejs/npm is removed from /usr/bin etc. Still doesn't seem to be working at all.

Answer (score 4):

Try `apt-get update`to update the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try

This will install node version manager (nvm) by typing the following at the command line.
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash`

Then activate nvm by typing the following at the command line.
`. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

Then Use nvm to install the version of Node.js you intend to use by typing the following at the command line.
`nvm install 4.4.5` (you can install 6.1.0 LTS for instance)

then test it by typing
`node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"`

Comment: To run nodejs, is it going to be nodejs in command line or node? Are they the same thing?

Comment: On cli you will need to type `node`

Comment: What do I do for NPM as-well?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing, usually people refer to node.js as node or nodejs just to short its name. Like when some people refer to react.js as react or reactjs. On cli, it's `node` the default created alias.

Comment: Node installs npm by default. Altough, you can update npm by typing `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: Hey, looks like I cannot run npm witout activating nvm. Is there a way I can make this command work globally.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've fixed my installation error because of rodete version limitation of linux.

Answer (score 0):

Install NPM and Node.js from the Official Ubuntu Repository.
First, connect to your server using ssh: ssh username @ server_ip_address 
After connecting, refresh the APT cache : sudo apt update 
Node.js setup : sudo apt install nodejs
You can also install NPM, the Node.js package manager: sudo apt install npm
Finally check the installed version : nodejs -v
To delete node.js, run this command: sudo apt remove nodejs